# How to NOT SELECT the OUTPUT value from a command shell script inside a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

I have a stored procedure which is used by an SSRS report.

But I need to run this before I run the query:

```
sys.xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd;
```

The problem is that running this first returns the OUTPUT cell. This throws off the report because it's expecting a proper query and not just "OUTPUT"

How do I go about omitting this OUTPUT SELECT? I tried to add "NO_OUTPUT" but it still does not work:

```
SET @sqlCmd = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageConverter\ImageConverter.exe", NO_OUTPUT';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your syntax for calling with the no_output clause may be the issue. Though the [MSDN docs show that syntax in one of the examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx), the MSDN listed syntax, as well as [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689(v=sql.80).aspx) suggests it is passed as a literal 2nd parameter to the xp_cmdshell procedure without the quotes, i.e.:

```
SET @sqlCmd = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageConverter\ImageConverter.exe"'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd, NO_OUTPUT;
```